# Splitting polygon with line in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, line, splitting

I am using ArcGIS Pro and I want to cut my polygon features with a line, as the output would be also a polygon. I have no special licences, so I am looking for an alternative way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

From the ArcGIS Pro Help on [Split a feature](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/split-a-feature.htm):

> In the Modify Features pane, Split divides a line or a polygon
>   feature into two or more features using a sketched line or a selection
>   of features as input.

Answer (score 1):

The tool available in ArcGIS Pro (feature to polygon) unfortunately requires an advanced licence. If you don't have too many lines, you could do it manually in an edit session thanks to the "split" tools. Otherwise, there could be a plug-in, but not that I know.